# ExtJS datepicker show open on render

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I want to show in a form a datepicker but not like a picker I want to show it opened like a calendar control.

Any clue on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just including it in the `items` of a component rather than a `datefield` field type...

```js
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    layout: 'vbox',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'datepicker',
            handler: function(picker, date){
                // fires when a new date is selected
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

... [works for me](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7lj).